# Use dropdown in views exposed filter on paragraph text field in paragraph view?

Tags: views, 8, paragraphs

I have it working for nodes but i tried for paragraph view and it is not working
Here is the code:

```
function hook_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

$storage = Drupal::getContainer()->get('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('paragraph');
$nids = $storage->getQuery();
$nids = $nids->condition('status', 1)
 ->execute();

if (!$nids) {
 return FALSE;
}


$options = [];
$nodes = $storage->loadMultiple($nids);


foreach ($nodes as $paragraph) {

    $value = $paragraph->field_pdf_title->value;
    $options[$value] = $value;

}


$form['field_pdf_title']['#type'] = 'select';
$form['field_pdf_title']['#options'] = $options;
$form['field_pdf_title']['#size'] = 1;
}
```

Comment: You should change `$nids` to `$pids` and `$nodes` to `$pagaraphs`. Anyhow, I think the culprit is this line `$nids = $nids->condition('status', 1)` as paragraphs don't have status, so get rid of this line.

Comment: I saw also that i have to enable ajax on the page otherwise the filter doesnt show up. But now i see all the title fields in the drop down not only the ones from the current node page (which were the only ones shown before adding the filter due to the contextual filter that I added) and when selecting any of them it always returns the fields from the "first paragraph" any idea why the filter is not working?

Comment: _It is not working_ is a vague statement. You should say what exactly you obtain and how that is different from what you expect. @NoSssweat is correct about the status not being implemented for _Paragraphs_ entities.

Comment: As side note, `hook_form_alter()` implementations don't return any value, so that `return FALSE;` must be removed too.